# How to query data of a specific table in all the databases without going into the database individually?

Tags: sql, sql-server

One of my clients has following setup in their SQL Server environments: each of their customers has their own database, called `Customer1db`, `Customer2db`, and so on. Each of these databases has the exactly same tables and exactly same structure, but just different data.

Let's say there is a `TableA` and `ColumnA` in those databases. Is there a way to query the data in `ColumnA` in each of these databases without doing

```
select ColumnA from TableA
```

in each of the databases?

Comment: This is an awfull design! You might use a `VIEW` combining with several `UNION ALL SELECT ...` statements...

Comment: Well, sometimes, the DB designs are out of my control, as it is in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
EXECUTE master.sys.sp_MSforeachdb 
'USE [?]; 
 if db_id()>4 
  begin
 select col from dbo.tbl
 end'
```

the above will exclude system db's. you can change query to exclude more